# Как найти все публичные методы в классе?

Tags: php, рефлексия

Есть дерективы dir1/dir/../../и.тд.
В каждной из них есть классы, я получил названия классов в многомеррный масив.
ключ это названия папки а в нем массив с ключем названия файла и значения названия класса.

```
[dir] => Array
        (
            [qwe.php] => qwe
            [qwer.php] => qwer
        )

    [desktop] => Array
        (
            [desktop.php] => desktop
            [desktop1.php] => desktop1
            [desktop2.php] => desktop2
            [directory] => Array
                (
                    [directory.php] => directory
                    [directory1.php] => directory1
                )
```

Мне нужно найти все публичные методу данных классов, как это сделать ? 
Можно через reflection но я не совсем понимаю как.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$class = new ReflectionClass('Ваш класс');
$methods = $class->getMethods(ReflectionMethod::IS_PUBLIC);
```